# How to modify the subfields of a custom field in hook presave

Tags: entities

I have a custom field in a custom module that consists of 4 varchar type values. Each of these subfields are called 'prefix', 'suffix', 'body' and 'header'.

In the hook presave, I want to modify only one of them, 'prefix', however, I can't do it:

```
function custom_field_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  switch ($entity->bundle()) {
    case 'custom_object':
      //This seems to modify all de field instead only the subfield 'prefix'
      $entity->set('field_multifield', ['prefix' => '55555']);
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Right, you overwrite the value with your set statement. Instead, first get the value of your field. Then modify that value's prefix. Then set the value to the newly modified one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sonfd commented you could get the field content as array:

```
$values = $entity->get('field_multifield')->getValue();
```

modify this array

```
$values[0]['prefix'] = '55555';
```

and then replace the entire field content:

```
$entity->set('field_multifield', $values);
```

Much easier though would be accessing a single property directly:

```
$entity->field_multifield->prefix = '55555';
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks to both of you (@sonfd).